# "System program problem detected" Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, crash, gdm

After upgrading from Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04 following error message appears after logging in to the desktop. How can I find the underlying problem? I know apport can be disabled but that will be a last resort.

```
System program problem detected
```

It seems to be connected to the `update notifier`program since that is the "name" of the window.

Following crashrapport is then created `/var/crash/_usr_sbin_gdm3.0.crash`

**Tested without success:**

1) `apt remove gdm3` & `apt install gdm3`

Comment: To find the underlying problem, look for a .crash report in /var/crash.

Comment: How did you manage to update to 20.04?  There are no more updates for 18.04's architecture.

Comment: @Ollie I did it by running a force check update trough the terminal, cant remember the exact command. It was right when 20.04 was released.

Comment: @Ollie See this, https://linuxhandbook.com/upgrade-ubuntu-server-version/